# PHP : order by clause in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

i want to use orderby clause in the prepared statement.

following is my query

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT  send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status,sentby FROM `chat` WHERE cust_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cust_id);
$result=$stmt->execute();
```

Now where do i add order by(asc) in this query to sort it by date or id.

Please help

Comment: Where you usually would add order by clause

Answer (score 0):

You do it like this:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT  send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status,sentby FROM `chat` WHERE cust_id = ? ORDER BY id ASC");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cust_id);
$result=$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

As in normal SQL query: at the end of query:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare(
    "SELECT
       send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status, sentby
     FROM `chat`
     WHERE cust_id=?
     ORDER BY id DESC"
);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $cust_id);
$result=$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add at the end of query, following is an example in which I added ascending order clause.

```
   $stmt = $connect->prepare(
        "SELECT
           send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status, sentby
         FROM `chat`
         WHERE cust_id=?
         ORDER BY id ASC"
    );
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $cust_id);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
```

The above query will return the record with ascending order of `id`, since we are using order clause on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in mysql order by is used at the end of the statement. like

```
SELECT  send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status,sentby FROM `chat` WHERE cust_id=? order by id
```

you can order by id,name or anything you want just write the name of that field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT  send_stamp,id,receiverid, message, time, status,sentby FROM `chat` WHERE cust_id=? ORDER  BY date ASC");
```

Comment: Please explain your code block, how it works and why it is suitable. That way people will notice your answers